My android projects getting these errors. What is happening and how I can solve it?
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'.
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:detachedConfiguration6'.
   > Multiple build operations failed.
         Immutable workspace contents have been modified: C:\Users\pctbo\.gradle\caches\transforms-4\bb4bf547ee257a96dcca66ff7f5d0566. These workspace directories are not supposed to be modified once they are created. Deleting the directory in question can allow the content to be recreated.
         Immutable workspace contents have been modified: C:\Users\pctbo\.gradle\caches\transforms-4\3028fa2516f658767969fcd9ae0fd134. These workspace directories are not supposed to be modified once they are created. Deleting the directory in question can allow the content to be recreated.
         Immutable workspace contents have been modified: C:\Users\pctbo\.gradle\caches\transforms-4\433e5dd7d0eab8ca733ee2b645e3e421. These workspace directories are not supposed to be modified once they are created. Deleting the directory in question can allow the content to be recreated.
         Immutable workspace contents have been modified: C:\Users\pctbo\.gradle\caches\transforms-4\88fb4862df823a6b4b73a205304a4a4d. These workspace directories are not supposed to be modified once they are created. Deleting the directory in question can allow the content to be recreated.
         Immutable workspace contents have been modified: C:\Users\pctbo\.gradle\caches\transforms-4\5400662f141ad1f2a6f3abf2e9197181. These workspace directories are not supposed to be modified once they are created. Deleting the directory in question can allow the content to be recreated.
         Immutable workspace contents have been modified: C:\Users\pctbo\.gradle\caches\transforms-4\4d495141b68e53c5abca64328972f836. These workspace directories are not supposed to be modified once they are created. Deleting the directory in question can allow the content to be recreated.
         Immutable workspace contents have been modified: C:\Users\pctbo\.gradle\caches\transforms-4\4f75e11a8bf62c3e8b6ad026344ae803. These workspace directories are not supposed to be modified once they are created. Deleting the directory in question can allow the content to be recreated.
         Immutable workspace contents have been modified: C:\Users\pctbo\.gradle\caches\transforms-4\733123ab4787e4f1451c287552fe83e9. These workspace directories are not supposed to be modified once they are created. Deleting the directory in question can allow the content to be recreated.
         Immutable workspace contents have been modified: C:\Users\pctbo\.gradle\caches\transforms-4\69e229ddb681a906680e870d78ff7603. These workspace directories are not supposed to be modified once they are created. Deleting the directory in question can allow the content to be recreated.
         Immutable workspace contents have been modified: C:\Users\pctbo\.gradle\caches\transforms-4\e85fdc91e968a61089956aec0edb3a92. These workspace directories are not supposed to be modified once they are created. Deleting the directory in question can allow the content to be recreated.
         ...and 52 more failures.
      > Immutable workspace contents have been modified: C:\Users\pctbo\.gradle\caches\transforms-4\bb4bf547ee257a96dcca66ff7f5d0566. These workspace directories are not supposed to be modified once they are created. Deleting the directory in question can allow the content to be recreated.
      > Immutable workspace contents have been modified: C:\Users\pctbo\.gradle\caches\transforms-4\3028fa2516f658767969fcd9ae0fd134. These workspace directories are not supposed to be modified once they are created. Deleting the directory in question can allow the content to be recreated.
      > Immutable workspace contents have been modified: C:\Users\pctbo\.gradle\caches\transforms-4\433e5dd7d0eab8ca733ee2b645e3e421. These workspace directories are not supposed to be modified once they are created. Deleting the directory in question can allow the content to be recreated.
      > Immutable workspace contents have been modified: C:\Users\pctbo\.gradle\caches\transforms-4\88fb4862df823a6b4b73a205304a4a4d. These workspace directories are not supposed to be modified once they are created. Deleting the directory in question can allow the content to be recreated.
      > Immutable workspace contents have been modified: C:\Users\pctbo\.gradle\caches\transforms-4\5400662f141ad1f2a6f3abf2e9197181. These workspace directories are not supposed to be modified once they are created. Deleting the directory in question can allow the content to be recreated.
      > Immutable workspace contents have been modified: C:\Users\pctbo\.gradle\caches\transforms-4\4d495141b68e53c5abca64328972f836. These workspace directories are not supposed to be modified once they are created. Deleting the directory in question can allow the content to be recreated.
      > Immutable workspace contents have been modified: C:\Users\pctbo\.gradle\caches\transforms-4\4f75e11a8bf62c3e8b6ad026344ae803. These workspace directories are not supposed to be modified once they are created. Deleting the directory in question can allow the content to be recreated.
      > Immutable workspace contents have been modified: C:\Users\pctbo\.gradle\caches\transforms-4\733123ab4787e4f1451c287552fe83e9. These workspace directories are not supposed to be modified once they are created. Deleting the directory in question can allow the content to be recreated.
      > Immutable workspace contents have been modified: C:\Users\pctbo\.gradle\caches\transforms-4\69e229ddb681a906680e870d78ff7603. These workspace directories are not supposed to be modified once they are created. Deleting the directory in question can allow the content to be recreated.
      > Immutable workspace contents have been modified: C:\Users\pctbo\.gradle\caches\transforms-4\e85fdc91e968a61089956aec0edb3a92. These workspace directories are not supposed to be modified once they are created. Deleting the directory in question can allow the content to be recreated.
      > Immutable workspace contents have been modified: C:\Users\pctbo\.gradle\caches\transforms-4\a32086ed188cb604faa10094dd432dfb. These workspace directories are not supposed to be modified once they are created. Deleting the directory in question can allow the content to be recreated.
      > Immutable workspace contents have been modified: C:\Users\pctbo\.gradle\caches\transforms-4\06e3ef2638bc361e4c44d066163c57ba. These workspace directories are not supposed to be modified once they are created. Deleting the directory in question can allow the content to be recreated.
      > Immutable workspace contents have been modified: C:\Users\pctbo\.gradle\caches\transforms-4\e55562c41530d176369e2dc1cc6ffe70. These workspace directories are not supposed to be modified once they are created. Deleting the directory in question can allow the content to be recreated.
      > Immutable workspace contents have been modified: C:\Users\pctbo\.gradle\caches\transforms-4\e55562c41530d176369e2dc1cc6ffe70. These workspace directories are not supposed to be modified once they are created. Deleting the directory in question can allow the content to be recreated.
      > Immutable workspace contents have been modified: C:\Users\pctbo\.gradle\caches\transforms-4\f0883ccf7906c2d708ce8c561048166d. These workspace directories are not supposed to be modified once they are created. Deleting the directory in question can allow the content to be recreated.
      > Immutable workspace contents have been modified: C:\Users\pctbo\.gradle\caches\transforms-4\25049f328fc924e27bcf57e7940ea173. These workspace directories are not supposed to be modified once they are created. Deleting the directory in question can allow the content to be recreated.
      > Immutable workspace contents have been modified: C:\Users\pctbo\.gradle\caches\transforms-4\025163681c8fb80f540c0697c84de911. These workspace directories are not supposed to be modified once they are created. Deleting the directory in question can allow the content to be recreated.
      > Immutable workspace contents have been modified: C:\Users\pctbo\.gradle\caches\transforms-4\59ef7fe466c0aa769f124fa8575ae2ff. These workspace directories are not supposed to be modified once they are created. Deleting the directory in question can allow the content to be recreated.
      > Immutable workspace contents have been modified: C:\Users\pctbo\.gradle\caches\transforms-4\68d2564d93c6719cbde332d7f677a577. These workspace directories are not supposed to be modified once they are created. Deleting the directory in question can allow the content to be recreated.
      > Immutable workspace contents have been modified: C:\Users\pctbo\.gradle\caches\transforms-4\032c6104676b844aa8fca3654dcd92f7. These workspace directories are not supposed to be modified once they are created. Deleting the directory in question can allow the content to be recreated.
      > Immutable workspace contents have been modified: C:\Users\pctbo\.gradle\caches\transforms-4\fc7d0fc678d431ce4d45fc3d5b65d000. These workspace directories are not supposed to be modified once they are created. Deleting the directory in question can allow the content to be recreated.
      > Immutable workspace contents have been modified: C:\Users\pctbo\.gradle\caches\transforms-4\dceb300961b48c8ab6d12ac906e3a4e5. These workspace directories are not supposed to be modified once they are created. Deleting the directory in question can allow the content to be recreated.
      > Immutable workspace contents have been modified: C:\Users\pctbo\.gradle\caches\transforms-4\9acb1dd8c6be79deb69e0160de8a2eee. These workspace directories are not supposed to be modified once they are created. Deleting the directory in question can allow the content to be recreated.
      > Immutable workspace contents have been modified: C:\Users\pctbo\.gradle\caches\transforms-4\ff0cbe0b2b44e868b0e54b7dbd85a810. These workspace directories are not supposed to be modified once they are created. Deleting the directory in question can allow the content to be recreated.
      > Immutable workspace contents have been modified: C:\Users\pctbo\.gradle\caches\transforms-4\d0123259983a23fc9f9894d3e526a849. These workspace directories are not supposed to be modified once they are created. Deleting the directory in question can allow the content to be recreated.
      > Immutable workspace contents have been modified: C:\Users\pctbo\.gradle\caches\transforms-4\ff0cbe0b2b44e868b0e54b7dbd85a810. These workspace directories are not supposed to be modified once they are created. Deleting the directory in question can allow the content to be recreated.
      > Immutable workspace contents have been modified: C:\Users\pctbo\.gradle\caches\transforms-4\ff0cbe0b2b44e868b0e54b7dbd85a810. These workspace directories are not supposed to be modified once they are created. Deleting the directory in question can allow the content to be recreated.
      > Immutable workspace contents have been modified: C:\Users\pctbo\.gradle\caches\transforms-4\928e13a16d654a1db78d8e0f6f39c2f9. These workspace directories are not supposed to be modified once they are created. Deleting the directory in question can allow the content to be recreated.
      > Immutable workspace contents have been modified: C:\Users\pctbo\.gradle\caches\transforms-4\e242d9255a3e6ae82eac6571e13df043. These workspace directories are not supposed to be modified once they are created. Deleting the directory in question can allow the content to be recreated.
      > Immutable workspace contents have been modified: C:\Users\pctbo\.gradle\caches\transforms-4\012d458fbba51d4460dd19bd3ba88802. These workspace directories are not supposed to be modified once they are created. Deleting the directory in question can allow the content to be recreated.
      > Immutable workspace contents have been modified: C:\Users\pctbo\.gradle\caches\transforms-4\012d458fbba51d4460dd19bd3ba88802. These workspace directories are not supposed to be modified once they are created. Deleting the directory in question can allow the content to be recreated.
      > Immutable workspace contents have been modified: C:\Users\pctbo\.gradle\caches\transforms-4\012d458fbba51d4460dd19bd3ba88802. These workspace directories are not supposed to be modified once they are created. Deleting the directory in question can allow the content to be recreated.
      > Immutable workspace contents have been modified: C:\Users\pctbo\.gradle\caches\transforms-4\012d458fbba51d4460dd19bd3ba88802. These workspace directories are not supposed to be modified once they are created. Deleting the directory in question can allow the content to be recreated.
      > Immutable workspace contents have been modified: C:\Users\pctbo\.gradle\caches\transforms-4\012d458fbba51d4460dd19bd3ba88802. These workspace directories are not supposed to be modified once they are created. Deleting the directory in question can allow the content to be recreated.
      > Immutable workspace contents have been modified: C:\Users\pctbo\.gradle\caches\transforms-4\fe7778786e1255614e31f9e65e47b96d. These workspace directories are not supposed to be modified once they are created. Deleting the directory in question can allow the content to be recreated.
      > Immutable workspace contents have been modified: C:\Users\pctbo\.gradle\caches\transforms-4\fe7778786e1255614e31f9e65e47b96d. These workspace directories are not supposed to be modified once they are created. Deleting the directory in question can allow the content to be recreated.
      > Immutable workspace contents have been modified: C:\Users\pctbo\.gradle\caches\transforms-4\a62200bea891fbe6115bb7d5af8aefba. These workspace directories are not supposed to be modified once they are created. Deleting the directory in question can allow the content to be recreated.
      > Immutable workspace contents have been modified: C:\Users\pctbo\.gradle\caches\transforms-4\fe7778786e1255614e31f9e65e47b96d. These workspace directories are not supposed to be modified once they are created. Deleting the directory in question can allow the content to be recreated.
      > Immutable workspace contents have been modified: C:\Users\pctbo\.gradle\caches\transforms-4\a62200bea891fbe6115bb7d5af8aefba. These workspace directories are not supposed to be modified once they are created. Deleting the directory in question can allow the content to be recreated.
      > Immutable workspace contents have been modified: C:\Users\pctbo\.gradle\caches\transforms-4\6618ca60ca509c4c1b86278dd8a2e572. These workspace directories are not supposed to be modified once they are created. Deleting the directory in question can allow the content to be recreated.
      > Immutable workspace contents have been modified: C:\Users\pctbo\.gradle\caches\transforms-4\d39372894a67351fffd395bf994eb797. These workspace directories are not supposed to be modified once they are created. Deleting the directory in question can allow the content to be recreated.
      > Immutable workspace contents have been modified: C:\Users\pctbo\.gradle\caches\transforms-4\6618ca60ca509c4c1b86278dd8a2e572. These workspace directories are not supposed to be modified once they are created. Deleting the directory in question can allow the content to be recreated.
      > Immutable workspace contents have been modified: C:\Users\pctbo\.gradle\caches\transforms-4\6d64855db52ff456c71cc3fda314f4ec. These workspace directories are not supposed to be modified once they are created. Deleting the directory in question can allow the content to be recreated.
      > Immutable workspace contents have been modified: C:\Users\pctbo\.gradle\caches\transforms-4\d4e8fc0151e78984f0d25470daeec264. These workspace directories are not supposed to be modified once they are created. Deleting the directory in question can allow the content to be recreated.
      > Immutable workspace contents have been modified: C:\Users\pctbo\.gradle\caches\transforms-4\6d380e816a86cab35fecd6fb992aa7e9. These workspace directories are not supposed to be modified once they are created. Deleting the directory in question can allow the content to be recreated.
      > Immutable workspace contents have been modified: C:\Users\pctbo\.gradle\caches\transforms-4\d4e8fc0151e78984f0d25470daeec264. These workspace directories are not supposed to be modified once they are created. Deleting the directory in question can allow the content to be recreated.
      > Immutable workspace contents have been modified: C:\Users\pctbo\.gradle\caches\transforms-4\d4e8fc0151e78984f0d25470daeec264. These workspace directories are not supposed to be modified once they are created. Deleting the directory in question can allow the content to be recreated.
      > Immutable workspace contents have been modified: C:\Users\pctbo\.gradle\caches\transforms-4\d4e8fc0151e78984f0d25470daeec264. These workspace directories are not supposed to be modified once they are created. Deleting the directory in question can allow the content to be recreated.
      > Immutable workspace contents have been modified: C:\Users\pctbo\.gradle\caches\transforms-4\d4e8fc0151e78984f0d25470daeec264. These workspace directories are not supposed to be modified once they are created. Deleting the directory in question can allow the content to be recreated.
      > Immutable workspace contents have been modified: C:\Users\pctbo\.gradle\caches\transforms-4\d4e8fc0151e78984f0d25470daeec264. These workspace directories are not supposed to be modified once they are created. Deleting the directory in question can allow the content to be recreated.
      > Immutable workspace contents have been modified: C:\Users\pctbo\.gradle\caches\transforms-4\d4e8fc0151e78984f0d25470daeec264. These workspace directories are not supposed to be modified once they are created. Deleting the directory in question can allow the content to be recreated.
      > Immutable workspace contents have been modified: C:\Users\pctbo\.gradle\caches\transforms-4\aa472d34d5994b60e33ecdad32786684. These workspace directories are not supposed to be modified once they are created. Deleting the directory in question can allow the content to be recreated.
      > Immutable workspace contents have been modified: C:\Users\pctbo\.gradle\caches\transforms-4\ac8a39e6c0fab5b0d4570822bb0007de. These workspace directories are not supposed to be modified once they are created. Deleting the directory in question can allow the content to be recreated.
      > Immutable workspace contents have been modified: C:\Users\pctbo\.gradle\caches\transforms-4\ed44759c79587053961bb0686c9038e2. These workspace directories are not supposed to be modified once they are created. Deleting the directory in question can allow the content to be recreated.
      > Immutable workspace contents have been modified: C:\Users\pctbo\.gradle\caches\transforms-4\6cfe6c692fa873a72749ea15a041f7fb. These workspace directories are not supposed to be modified once they are created. Deleting the directory in question can allow the content to be recreated.
      > Immutable workspace contents have been modified: C:\Users\pctbo\.gradle\caches\transforms-4\d59d15dca904fef193d76fa61e51e376. These workspace directories are not supposed to be modified once they are created. Deleting the directory in question can allow the content to be recreated.
      > Immutable workspace contents have been modified: C:\Users\pctbo\.gradle\caches\transforms-4\170927ed14cd9044f77c9436ecd5c915. These workspace directories are not supposed to be modified once they are created. Deleting the directory in question can allow the content to be recreated.
      > Immutable workspace contents have been modified: C:\Users\pctbo\.gradle\caches\transforms-4\cee370f1cc563801e337822a529d390e. These workspace directories are not supposed to be modified once they are created. Deleting the directory in question can allow the content to be recreated.
      > Immutable workspace contents have been modified: C:\Users\pctbo\.gradle\caches\transforms-4\796489593314daed73ccc84451d9c8fc. These workspace directories are not supposed to be modified once they are created. Deleting the directory in question can allow the content to be recreated.
      > Immutable workspace contents have been modified: C:\Users\pctbo\.gradle\caches\transforms-4\3896d65fed409b2dea986976840215ed. These workspace directories are not supposed to be modified once they are created. Deleting the directory in question can allow the content to be recreated.
      > Immutable workspace contents have been modified: C:\Users\pctbo\.gradle\caches\transforms-4\45b07c309e8b9b4096b6aec5f2582787. These workspace directories are not supposed to be modified once they are created. Deleting the directory in question can allow the content to be recreated.
      > Immutable workspace contents have been modified: C:\Users\pctbo\.gradle\caches\transforms-4\45b07c309e8b9b4096b6aec5f2582787. These workspace directories are not supposed to be modified once they are created. Deleting the directory in question can allow the content to be recreated.


Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.

This happened to me once my pc got turned off suddenly. I followed following steps to get it solved -

There is a path shown in the error. In your case, its
C:\Users\pctbo.gradle\caches\transforms-4\.....

In your File Explorer(Windows) or File Finder(mac), go to folder

 transforms-4 as shown in your path


Delete that folder.

Close Android Studio and restart again same project.

Clean build

Rebuild project



To solve this problem follow these steps:

Close the project that you are trying to run.
Go to the caches folder by pasting this path to file explorer. C:\Users\pctbo.gradle\caches\
Delete all the files and folders (jars-9, journal-1,modules-2,transfroms-4, etc.) in the caches folder.
Open the project again ( this time it will take more time as it will download all the dependencies missing from the caches folder you deleted.
Run the project. It should work.

